# Python Subplot Does Not Show Legend

Tags: python, matplotlib

I tried to plot two graphs with the same page and there is a problem about legends in the graphs. Legends are shown in the second graph yet not shown in the first graph. I did not get the problem. Can you help me?

Here is my code.

```
#plot training and validation values
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2,1, figsize=(25, 25))
ax1.plot(model.history.history['loss'], color='g', label="Training loss")
ax1.plot(model.history.history['val_loss'], color='y', label="validation loss")
ax1.set_xticks(np.arange(10, 250, 10))
ax2.plot(model.history.history['acc'], color='b', label="Training accuracy")
ax2.plot(model.history.history['val_acc'], color='r',label="Validation accuracy")
ax2.set_xticks(np.arange(10, 250, 10))
plt.xlabel("Num. of epochs")
plt.ylabel("Accuracy")
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[Here is the output of the graphs](https://ibb.co/mqsHv7Y)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set labels for each ax

```
ax1.set_xlabel("Num. of epochs")
ax2.set_xlabel("Num. of epochs")
ax1.set_ylabel("Loss")
ax2.set_ylabel("Accuracy")
ax1.legend()
ax2.legend()
```